# Why inDaylightTime() method returning wrong in timezone?

Tags: java, timezone, dst

My first print shows that daylight saving starts from 8th March, whereas to check that I have passed my custom date(9th March) to timeZone.inDaylightTime(calendar.getTime()), whereas it is returning false.Where I am going wrong ?

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern");
    System.out.println("TimeZone ::: "+timeZone);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2019);

    boolean b = timeZone.inDaylightTime(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println("Is the day in daylight saving "+b);
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also `US/Eastern` is the deprecated name for that time zone, prefer `America/New_York`.

Comment: @Ole, could you please post a small example by using those ZoneId and ZonedDateTime to get dayLightSaving date exists or  anylink ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DST wasn't in effect in the U.S. Eastern zone on March 9th, 2019. It went into effect March 10th at 2 a.m. [See timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york).

> My first print shows that daylight saving starts from 8th March...

I'm guessing you're basing that on this:

> startMode=3,
> startMonth=2,
> startDay=8,
> startDayOfWeek=1,
> startTime=7200000

Remember that DST changes (in the U.S. at least) always happen early on a Sunday morning. What that rule says is that the first Sunday on or after March 8th is when the change should occur, not that it should occur *on* March 8th (which was a Friday). The law says it starts the second Sunday in March (at the moment, it's varied periodically), so by saying the first Sunday on or after March 8th, the code fits the definition "second Sunday of March."

You can see this concept in the description of [`SimpleTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html):

> To construct a SimpleTimeZone with a daylight saving time schedule, the schedule can be described with a set of rules, start-rule and end-rule. A day when daylight saving time starts or ends is specified by a combination of month, day-of-month, and day-of-week values. The month value is represented by a Calendar MONTH field value, such as Calendar.MARCH. The day-of-week value is represented by a Calendar DAY_OF_WEEK value, such as SUNDAY. The meanings of value combinations are as follows.
>
> - **Exact day of month**
>   To specify an exact day of month, set the month and day-of-month to an exact value, and day-of-week to zero. For example, to specify March 1, set the month to MARCH, day-of-month to 1, and day-of-week to 0.
> - **Day of week on or after day of month**
>   To specify a day of week on or after an exact day of month, set the month to an exact month value, day-of-month to the day on or after which the rule is applied, and day-of-week to a negative DAY_OF_WEEK field value. For example, to specify the second Sunday of April, set month to APRIL, day-of-month to 8, and day-of-week to -SUNDAY.
> - **Day of week on or before day of month**
>   To specify a day of the week on or before an exact day of the month, set day-of-month and day-of-week to a negative value. For example, to specify the last Wednesday on or before the 21st of March, set month to MARCH, day-of-month is -21 and day-of-week is -WEDNESDAY.
> - **Last day-of-week of month**
>   To specify, the last day-of-week of the month, set day-of-week to a DAY_OF_WEEK value and day-of-month to -1. For example, to specify the last Sunday of October, set month to OCTOBER, day-of-week to SUNDAY and day-of-month to -1.

Comment: Hi Crowder, Thanks for the detailed explanation, but I am unable to set day-of-week to -SUNDAY as specified by you. like calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, SUNDAY);

Comment: @srinivas - You're misreading the JavaDoc above. You use `-SUNDAY` when constructing a `SimpleTimeZone` to tell it to use that mode. The main point of the answer is: The code isn't giving you the wrong answer, `false` is correct for the date you're specifying in the U.S. Eastern time zone.

Comment: :) Got it, Thank you Crowder.

Answer (score 1):

> could you please post a small example by using those ZoneId and
>   ZonedDateTime to get dayLightSaving date exists

It’ll be my pleasure.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZonedDateTime testTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, zone);

    boolean dst = zone.getRules().isDaylightSavings(testTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println("Is the day in daylight saving " + dst);
```

> Is the day in daylight saving false

As stated in the other answer, summer time (DST) began last Sunday, March 10, in North America this year. So let’s try with that day at 5 AM — then we should get `true`.

```
    ZonedDateTime testTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 3, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, zone);
```

> Is the day in daylight saving true

`zone.getRules()` returns a `ZoneRules` object. Such an object knows everything about the UTC offset for the time zone, also about DST. So we can query it with an `Instant`. We get an `Instant` from `testTime.toInstant()`.

**Link:** Section [Time Zone and Offset Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html) in the Oracle tutorial (including an example of using `ZoneRules` that somewhat resembles mine).